# Backward from infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinity

The following question has been raised and answered lately:

- [Problem 6 - IMO 1985](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759599/problem-6-imo-1985)

Please take a look at the *Reverse method* part of the 
[answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759599/problem-6-imo-1985/858781#858781)
given by [this author](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/96057/han-de-bruijn).
What's happening there is that we start with some "infinitely" large number $n=$LARGE,
some accompanying value of $1-1/(n+1) < x_{n+1} < 1$ - the precise value of $x_{n+1}$ doesn't matter much - and then iterate down to $n=1$ where the desired value $x_1$ is found. I've learned that this is called 
[Backward Recursion](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576110/how-to-find-this-limit-a-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt1-sqrt-frac12-sqrt-fr/583267#583267) .
The LARGEr the number $n$ we start with, the more accurate the value of $x_1$ will be;
that accuracy is improving with an amount of approximately $\times 1/2$ with every single
increase LARGE := LARGE $+ 1$ which is one significant bit at a time. 
This is the basic Backward Recursive formula:
$$
x_n := \frac{x_{n+1}}{\frac{1}{2n}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2+x_{n+1}}}
$$
Our excercise has been limited by 64 bits double precision of standard Delphi Pascal.
Note that LARGE is the *only* variable in the programs that is responsible for
the limitations imposed.

But suppose that we have hardware and software at our disposal which is free of any
limitations - I've always thought that such an ideal machinery may be simply called
*mathematics* . In a truly mathematical machine we can make LARGE as large as we
want. Now the following **wild idea** comes into mind. Suppose that we start with $n=\infty$, hence $x_{\infty+1}=1$ and iterate back from infinity. Then informally we have (hope you get the idea, which is sort of limit LARGE $\to \infty$) :
$$
x_{\infty} := \frac{x_{\infty+1}}{\frac{1}{2\infty}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2\infty}\right)^2+x_{\infty+1}}} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x_\infty := \sqrt{x_{\infty+1}} = 1
$$
Therefore the next iterand, hence all iterands remain $1$ and finally $x_1 = 1$, which is wrong. So we are getting nowhere. (Surely that has been a long way back to go :-)
**Question:** Is there any way to yet depart from infinity, get around this "stuck with $1$" and 
arrive at the correct value of $x_1$?

Comment: $$x_n = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2 + x_{n+1}}-\frac{1}{2n}$$ is rationalising the denominator.

Comment: I think the fact that $x_{n+1}<1$ is important, meaning even $x_{\infty}$ is a little less than one and you won't be "stuck with $1$".

Comment: @Silynn: Yes, that's true. But _how much_ is that "little less" then ? Can we do something that is _independent_ of the _how much_ ?

Comment: When you count in set theory, you start with a base point (0), and then you get to other numbers by repeating the operation $+1$. However, to actually arrive at infinity, you have to use a new operation. You can do induction/recursion for infinite numbers, but you have to remember to deal with both operations, not just $+1$. I think to make sense of counting back down from infinity you need to make sense of undoing the second operation.